# Calculate discrete curvature of sliced mesh in meshlab

Tags: image-processing, computational-geometry, mesh, meshlab

As part of my undergraduate research, I am looking to calculate the internal contact angle of water inside of a gas diffusion layer (GDL), a porous component of hydrogen fuel cells made of primarily carbon fibers, via image analysis. Ultimately, I want to take a 3D mesh of water and analyze its average curvature, which would allow me to calculate the average contact angle.

To do so, I have pre-segmented tomography images of a dry and wet stack of the same GDL (.tiff). I merged the two segmented stacks to create a new merged stack, where the GDL is red and the water is blue. One image of the merged stack is shown below.

[Screenshot of merged stack of segmented GDL and water tomography stacks. Note that the red 'dots' are cross-sections of carbon fibers. The top and bottom red boundaries are plastic covers around the GDL during water injection and are to be ignored.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAaRN.png)

Using ImageJ's 3D Viewer plugin, I created a mesh of the merged stack, and set the thresholding value so that only the water (blue) would show. I saved this as a binary STL file.

[Screenshot of 3D mesh of water injected into a GDL, showing water only.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JL4Ni.jpg)

Then, I uploaded that file into meshlab, where, after several iterations of surface-preserving Laplacian smoothing, I calculated the mean curvature using the [Filters > Normals, Curvature and Orientation > Discrete Curvature] tool. When I applied the [Render > Show Quality Histogram] feature, I noticed the average curvature shows up as 0, due to the bottom of the mesh being completely flat.

[Screenshot of mesh in meshlab with histogram of curvatures to the left.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jx8Z.png)

**I want to calculate the average curvature, but for a specific part of the mesh; i.e., excluding the outside edges of the mesh and excluding the bottom of the mesh.** How should I go about doing this?

(Also, I am very new to image analysis, meshes, computational geometry, and meshlab. If anyone has any suggestions on better ways to go about finding the average curvature or contact angle I am all ears.)

---UPDATE---

I realized there is an alternative solution that suits the needs of my project much better. Thus, I am not going to pursue the meshlab route anymore. (Nonetheless, thanks @akio.tanaka for the input.)

Comment: Are you coding this in a particular language? Python?

Comment: @mishsx I haven't decided on a language yet, but it would likely come down to Python or Matlab. Those are the only two languages I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

Before calculating curvature, you should delete some faces which you don't want to calculate curvature in this case. "Conditional Face Selection" Filter can help it.
You can use the filter from [Filters] -> [Selection] -> [Conditional Face Selection].

The image below is sample to select faces which have z component of each vertex normal is larger than 0.5. Red faces are selected ones. You can delete the faces with press "delete" key at this situation:

[image]

Comment: I see, this is very helpful. After trying it, though, I'm afraid it still hasn't solved my problem. When I calculated the mean curvature for the entire mesh, the mode was 0, or very close to it. Even after selecting the faces via your suggestion, the mode was still 0.

Comment: @ChrisLiu Is it possible to upload mesh files which you are trying to improve output?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not able to do that. It's proprietary data.